# can't add everything together? (stuck on the last code)

Tags: python-2.7

*ignore this part, just look at the last few codes. im trying to add all the quanties together but the last code prints every purchase individually? How can i get it to print "Your purchases is" and add the quanties times their price all in one line instead of printing it for every individual

```
print "Enter a fruit name (or done):",
fruit = raw_input()
fruit_list = []
while fruit != "done":
 fruit_list = fruit_list + [fruit]
 print "Enter a fruit name (or done):",
 fruit = raw_input()





price_list = []
for x in range(0, len(fruit_list)):
 print "Enter the price for " + fruit_list[x] + ":",
 price = float(raw_input())
 price_list = price_list + [price]

# print " Your fruit list is:" + str(fruit_list)
# print "Your price list is:" + str(price_list)

print fruit_list
print price_list


quanity_list = []
for x in range(0, len(fruit_list)):
 print str(fruit_list[x]) + str(price_list[x]) + " Quantity:",
 quantity = int(raw_input())
 print "Your total purchase is:", + price_list[x] * quantity
```

Comment: You need to move printing "Your total purchase is ..." out of the loop.

Comment: Also you need to actually calculate the sum of all items somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code : 
Replace your last part of code with;

```
 total = 0
 quanity_list = []
 for x in range(0, len(fruit_list)):
    print str(fruit_list[x]) + str(price_list[x]) + " Quantity:",
    quantity = int(raw_input())
    total = total + price_list[x] * quantity

 print "Your total purchase is:" + total
```

Comment: i got it and thanks and i added str(total) on the last line , that gave me an error but now i fixed it thanks.